# Maya, Python, Vray light not showing up for light linking

Tags: python, maya

In maya, when creating a Vray rectangle light with Python, I am using the Maya createNode(type = "VRayLightRectShape") command. I am able to create the light, but it does not show up in the defaultLightSet group, I have to manually join it to the group, and even then, the light is not seen by any relationship editors such as the light linking editor. If I create another light, using the Maya GUI, then both my script created light and the new light will appear in the editors, but upon deleting the GUI created light, my script created light will also disappear from the light linking relationship editor. I am using Maya 2015.  Am I missing a connection somewhere in the creation process? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the command :

`cmds.shadingNode('VRayLightRectShape', asLight=True)`

I don't have VRay so I can't test it but it should work.